# How to open a Flash project with some existing code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am a Java developer and have no experience in Flash, so sorry in advance if some of my questions will look stupid :)

I got some source code in this hierarchy and structure:

```
-sources flash builder
 -com
  -greensock
 -deng
  -fzip
  -utils
 -org
  -flintparticles
  ALAccessibility.as
  ALEvent.as
  ALImage.as
  ALVideo.as
  ALVideoOld.as
  Project.as
  Project-app.xml
```

Folders are marked with - sign. I didn't write in details what is inside of every folder (they have a lot of .as files)

How to open these files and folders as a Flash (I don't know exactly as an Action Script or Flex or something else) project? I also have project.swf file.

I have the Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be doing the import one folder too "high".

Usually the file structures you posted here are within a /src directory which is inside a project directory. There should be an Eclipse project file (.project) in the folder you're targeting for the import.

I don't think it works any differently from importing a Java project into Eclipse.

If that's not available, you'll have to create a new project and copy everything you have into that project structure - it's possible you've lost some project config (build path, compiler settings, etc) if the raw source is all you have...

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Builder. File -> Import Flash Builder Project. Select "Project Folder" and Browse to the folder. Follow any instructions that may appear afterward.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that before I posted. Unfortunately I got the message: "The folder does not contain a valid Flash Builder Project."

Comment: Then do File->New Project. You'll need to figure out what kind of project it is (looks like a plain ActionScript 3 project) and once that is created, past your files into the new project.

Comment: I created an ActionScript project and moved all the files I have into it. I tried to run my project in the browser but got just black window without any animation.

Comment: Did you set your project file to Project.as? The project is likely trying to run either PROJECTNAME.as or Main.as when it launches right now. You need to set it to be the Project.as (Right click the project, select Properties. Select ActionScript Applications. Select Project.as. "Set As Default")

Comment: Are you trying to import maven project?